# Redirecting rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this routes and it's routeing to /USERS/:username once all is said and done and I need it to route to /:username without the leading USERS.

```
resources :users do
get :autocomplete_user_name, :on => :collection
end    

autocomplete_user_name_users GET    /users/autocomplete_user_name(.:format)     users#autocomplete_user_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
resources :users, path: '' do
  get :autocomplete_user_name, :on => :collection
end
```